# convert String of c# to java using JNA

Tags: c#, java, jna

I am using JNA to deal with dll build in C#.
I have

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
public String serialNumber;
```

code in dll
How to match serialNumber in java?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Java's `String`?

It looks like C#'s `string` is the adequate translation to C's `char*`, and as Java's `string` is the adequate translation of C's `char*`, I would suppose it would work.